# Crystal Oscillator Has A Low Amplitude

Tags: oscillator, ethernet, crystal, high-frequency, esp32

I have an ECS-2520MV-500 on an unpopulated board that outputs this ~600mV pk-pk signal when I attach 3.3V and GND:

[image]

According to the oscillator datasheet, the output should have this voltage level:

```
Output voltage Level    VOL: 10%Vdd max/VOH: 90%Vdd min
```

This causing problems for the LAN8720A that relies on this signal since it doesn't meet the IL and IH requirements.
What could be causing the low amplitude of the signal?

Here is a picture of the board layout, currently it is all unpopulated so this is the entirety of the signal lines but the same behavior occurs when the whole board is populated.

[image]

There is also a ESP32 on the board that could potentially source the 50MHz signal but it shows the exact same behavior on all the IO pins that I checked (IO0 and IO17).

Comment: Are you satisfying the output load capacitance limit on it?

Comment: It's possible I'm exceeding it, it has a max output load of 15pF. Could the capacitance of a two layer PCB more than that? How would I go about measuring it?

Comment: Is the CLKEN high?

Comment: _"but **it** shows the exact same behavior on all the IO pins that I checked"_ - the ESP32? What has this got to do with your oscillator problem?

Comment: @Justme yes it is, there is 0V on the output of the oscillator when I attach CLKEN to ground

Comment: @BruceAbbott Sorry, that wasn't clear, I was referencing the scope I used to measure the signal with. I was trying to say that I'm having the same signal issue at multiple locations on the board, and with different ICs. So it most likely isn't just a bad oscillator.

Comment: _" I was referencing the scope I used"_ - Perhaps a bad ground connection? This can attenuate high frequencies while still showing correct dc voltages.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'll have to check that next time I'm in the lab, is 50MHz a high enough frequency for that kind of behavior?

Comment: Yes. At 50MHz you need the shortest possible grounding route from probe to board, with low resistance and inductance. https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/oscilloscope-ground-noise-concepts/

Comment: Just to check; you are using a X10 scope probe? A X1 will load the oscillator too much even if the probe has enough bandwidth.

Comment: Indeed, and the mouse popup most likely covers the 1x/10x setting which is important. 1x mode has bandwidth usually below 10MHz, which would explain why you get approximately correct 1.65V DC reading with small 50MHz sine wave superimposed. Never use 1x probes unless you know what you are doing, and always leave them on 10x when done.

Answer (score 3):

Silly answer to a silly question, it turns out I had the probe bandwidth set to 20MHz. After changing the BW to 1GHz a nice clean clock signal shows up.

Comment: I thought of that, but didn't see anything on the display to say that it was set to low bandwidth.